# how to get Jest --watch to run on changes to JSON/YAML files?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, yaml

I'm running some jest tests with `--watch` that depend on data fixtures. I want the watch run to trigger when I edit my data files, not just the code.
I've added the following to my `package.json` specifically adding `yaml` for `moduleFileExtensions` but still not having any luck. Based on:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-arraystring

Is there a setting I could make to the `package.json` to see if it's even getting picked up at all? I guess next step is to try with a `.js` config, throw some errors in and see if I'm barking up the wrong tree!

The yaml files are not part of an "import" or otherwise, they are just loaded by my code. So I'm hoping for a way that "touching" the files would re-trigger the watch to run.

Perhaps the watch command needs to also specify what data files to watch?

```
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "modulePaths": [
      "cdn",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "yaml"
    ]
```

Comment: What's your Jest config and how do you use these files? Watching works out of the box for modules that are imported in tests. If you don't load them with `require` or `import`, this obviously isn't expected to work.

Comment: the files are not code so they can't be required, they're YAML data. they are 'read' by my code tho. the watch loop is working on the code, but not on the data.

Answer (score 3):

[According to this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8496) `moduleFileExtensions` is the right place for configuring additional file extensions to watch. However instead of `modulePaths` you should use `roots` to configure directories that you want watched.

Jest definition of `modulePaths`:

> An alternative API to setting the NODE_PATH env variable, modulePaths is an array of absolute paths to additional locations to search when resolving modules.

Modules are resolved before the tests are executed and are not expected to change much. If you're wanting to add directories for Jest to watch then you might consider using the [`roots` config](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#roots-arraystring).

Jest definition of `roots`:

> A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in.

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/cdn",
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "node",
      "yaml",
      "yml"
    ]
  }
}
```

*Note that I also added "yml" to moduleFileExtensions just in case you're using yml/yaml.*

Comment: You can use the package `jest-config` to just add the extensions you need by doing `moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, "myext"]` as specified [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#options). The list of default extensions can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/main/packages/jest-config/src/Defaults.ts#L48).